# How to vertically align in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align the contents of my jumbotron at center in Bootstrap 4 (4.0.0-alpha.6). This happens fine in Chrome and Safari on the Mac desktop, but neither on my iOS devices, where the text still aligns to the top.

I am forcing the jumbotron to display taller than it otherwise would with min-height, to accommodate a background picture.

Here is the HTML...

```
<!-- jumbotron -->
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mb-0 cxt-bg-dark-grey cxt-bgimg-frame cxt-bgimg-tint cxt-bgimg-cook text-white text-center" style="min-height:500px"> <!-- .jumbotron-fluid and content in .container make jumbotron full-width and squared corners, cf. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/jumbotron/  -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 cxt-title">
        <h1 class="display-4 pb-2">Jumbotron title</h1>
        <p class="lead pb-4">Sub-title sub-title sub-title v sub-title sub-title sub-title sub-title </p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary pmd-ripple-effect btn-lg mb-4" href="#" role="button">Get Started</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS...

```
.cxt-bgimg-frame {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.cxt-bgimg-tint {
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.6);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.cxt-bgimg-cook {
  background-image:url('path/to/my/image.png');
}
```

The key part is...

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

As I said, it works fine on desktop, but not iOS devices like my iPad.

I have also tried adding some webkit references...

```
.cxt-bgimg-frame {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
 -ms-flex-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

... But that doesn't fix it.

I know, according to the release docs, that, as of Bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha 6, "Bootstrap 4 is now flexbox by default!" But I don't know whether that negates the need for me to call the flex stuff above.

How do I correctly get things to vertically align at center?

Solution should be a Bootstrap 4-centric solution.

Comment: Update - center aligning does not work on an iPad mini with iOS 8.4 but does work out okay on an iPad Air carrying iOS 10.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if you can use `flexbox` on a specific device, you need to look closer at the system + browser versions of your device and at [`caniuse flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

For prefixing your `CSS`, use [`autoprefixer`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). For maximum browser compat, input `> 0%` in the tiny settings box at the bottom of the page.

If you did all of the above, your code should render correctly on any device featuring iOS 7.0 or above.

---

In its current form, your code doesn't provide a cross-browser flexbox solution, nor is it using Bootstrap 4's flexbox implementation, which is why you have trouble on iOS devices.
In order to center using Bootstrap's `flexbox` classes, you need to:

- apply `.d-flex` and `.justify-content-center` on parent
- apply a sufficient `min-height` on the same parent
- apply `.align-self-center` on the child

Example:

```css
.cxt-bgimg-frame {
  min-height:100vh;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/1024/768') no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
}

.align-self-center.p-3 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.42);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.21);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 10px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 4px 18px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mb-0 cxt-bg-dark-grey cxt-bgimg-frame cxt-bgimg-tint cxt-bgimg-cook text-white d-flex justify-content-center"> 
  <div class="container align-self-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 cxt-title d-flex justify-content-center"  style="min-height:70vh">
        <div class="align-self-center text-center p-3">
          <h1 class="display-4 pb-2">Jumbotron title</h1>
          <p class="lead pb-4">Sub-title sub-title sub-title v sub-title sub-title sub-title sub-title </p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary pmd-ripple-effect btn-lg mb-4" href="#" role="button">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Answers to your comment questions:**

The example I provided above is ***generic***, aimed at helping anyone needing an example on Bootstrap 4's `flexbox` centering. You are completely free to change it to fit the specific needs of your project.

1. I added the styling to that box so you could see it. Of course you don't need to apply colors/shadows in your project.
2. Not necessarily. It depends on `flex-direction`. For a better understanding of the `flexbox` model I recommend [`a guide to flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [`current specs`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).
3. a) `vh` means "viewport height/100" - it's completely different from `100%`, because `100%` can be 5 times the viewport height, depending on your content, while `100vh` is always the viewport height. In today's web, `vh` is quite popular, as it enables you to have *"full page height panels"* which could be used with `scollTo()` type navigation. If you have a fixed navbar, you can use `min-height: calc(100vh - Npx)` where `N` is the size of your navbar in `px`.
   b) Yes, the slash `/` is intentional and it means "background-size". See [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) shorthand.

Comment: A couple of clarifications about this…

1. Re: align-self-center —
I don’t need the shaded box at all, so I won’t use the .align-self-center.p-3
 modifier. To clarify - looks like .align-self-center is an existing Bootstrap 4 flexbox class that is a simple way to vertically-align centre, right? And you were modifying the padding-3 version to add a shaded box? But I presume applying a plain “align-self-center” to the classes is still necessary for my vertical-alignment aims?

Comment: 2. justify-content-center —
Isn’t this for horizontal alignment? ie. text-center is gone. What’s the logic? Is this a flex box version of the horizontal alignment control I had using text-center?

Comment: 3. Re: jumbotron size/cover —
In my initial code, my jumbotron was not as high as this. I had the height expressed in my min-height, and it was shorter than the browser height. Now it is the full height of the browser window. I quite like it, actually - but I would also like to know how to peg it at a shallower height…

Comment: a) Thanks for showing me “vh” (vertical height?). Looks like I can control this using the 100vh in CSS and 70vh in your HTML code - but what is the interplay between each? 70vh seems to be 70% of the 100%? (And, hence, I could have 50% of 75% or something else?). But are both necessary? Removing the 70h from HTML seems to let the 100vh in CSS control it just fine, and I could just modify that number alone? I’m minded to just control the property in CSS, ie. reducing it to 80vh - is this okay?

Comment: b) Is the slash on your “/cover” intentional? It works properly with it, but, without it, the image blows up over the page.

Comment: I answered your questions in the answer's body. See linked docs. Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::)

Comment: Great answer, Andrei!